# Django: problem with format when using ajax query (string/Json)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django

I try to send data with ajax but the format is a string and I need JSON (or formated data)

Data to be sent are displayed in an HTML table.
I loop in all my rows to collect all data to be send using ajax.
But I have an error when I try to make a JSON object when using JSON.Parse(new_parameters).
If use new_parameters in my ajax query, I get False in my ajax view...
If I "stringify" new_parameters to use it in my ajax query, I get data in my ajax view but in string format...
That's mean the way I construct new_parameters is not a good way...

```
    var parameters = {};
    var current_parameters = [];
    var new_parameters = [];

    // Collect data from html data when user click on "Modify settings" button
    $(document).on('click', '#modifier', function(event) 
    {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $('#table_parametrage tr').each(function() {

            var parameter = {};
            $(this).find('td div').each (function() {

                parameter[$(this).attr("col_name")] = $(this).eq(0).html();
            }); 

            new_parameters.push(parameter);  
        });

        new_parameters.shift(); 

        // requête ajax > start
        // parameters = JSON.parse(new_parameters, null, 2);
        console.log(new_parameters);

        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }

        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).data("ajax-url"),
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
                'data' : new_parameters,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // alert(data);
            },
            error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
                //
            }
        });
        // requête ajax > end

        // Remise à zéro de la liste
        new_parameters = [];
        parameters = {};


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

for those interested, even if I am not ure it is the best code, I resolve my problem like this:

JS:

```
...
        parameters = JSON.stringify(new_parameters, null, 2);

        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }

        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $('#modifier').data("ajax-url"),
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
                'data' : parameters,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // alert(data);
            },
            error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
                //
            }
        });
```

```
# requete ajax
def ajax(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.POST.get('data',False)

        # https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json
        data_dict = json.loads(data)
        print(data_dict)
        print(data_dict[0]['ran_st1'])

    else:
        datas = ''
        print('echec')

    return render(request, 'randomization_settings/ajax.html', {})
```